# Is there words that mean "meet the criteria"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, synonyms, vocabulary

I'm making a comic strip and looking for a funny word in the theme of hair, maybe something that means "make it meet the criteria".

It is hard for me to explain, as my first language isn't English.

don't be shy of asking questions about my question :P

Comment: [compliant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/compliant) *- meeting or in accordance with rules or standards*

Comment: Do you have reason to thnk there is such a word in English? I'm curious if there is one in another language.

Comment: May I echo Jim's comment? Especially as I see nothing humorous or anything to do with "hair" in the accepted answer. Could you please describe the scene or something about the dialogue. Is the comic strip set in a hairdresser's for example?

Comment: RE: _It is hard for me to explain, as my first language isn't english_ - perhaps you'd be interested in paying a visit to [ell.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "comply", which means "meet specified standards."

For a similar word in theme of hair, how about adhere?

Adhere or rather "adhere to" is a synonym of comply.

Answer (score 2):

"Compliant" suggests that the criteria are normative and that the meeting of the criteria is intentional. For other cases I suggest "qualifying."